# How can I find an entity based on it's ID in a DBSet<>?

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext, dbset

I have a DB Addresses which contains Addresses, and every Address has an unique ID.
I need to write a method, which gets and ID as a parameter, and it has to check if an Address exists with a given ID is in the DB Addresses.

I tried the following:

```
var listOfRightIDs = dbContext.Addresses.Where(a => a.Id != givenAddress).ToList();
            if (listOfRightIDs.Count == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException();
```

Comment: Replace .where with FirstOrDefault and remove ToList that and also use == not != as it seems you want to search for address based on ID. This way if the address is not found the object will be null and if an address exists it will have an address.

Comment: That's what [DbSet.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?view=efcore-5.0) already does. All you need to do is `var address=dbContexgt.Addresses.Find(givenAddress)`

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to fetch an item with a specific primary key from a `DbSet<T>`:

- Use a query, ending with FirstOrDefault()
- Use [DbSet.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.find?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

> **DbSet.Find:** If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity

Which of the two you should use depends on usage: if you fetch the item, then do some calculations, while someone else changes the item in the database, and you want to use the item again, do you want the originally fetched item, or do you want the updated item?

Also: do you fetch the data because you want to update the fetched data in the database, or because you only want to use the fetched data?

Your DbContext has a [ChangeTracker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). Whenever you Find, or query data without using Select, the fetched data and a copy of it are put in the ChangeTracker. You get a reference to the copy (or maybe the original, but as they are the same, that does not matter)

If you make changes to the fetched data, you change the copy. When you call `SaveChanges`, the values of the original are compared to the values of the copy. If they are changed, the item is updated in the database.

If you use `Find` to fetch a complete item, and you use Find again, to fetch the same item, you get the value from the ChangeTracker. If you use a query the item is fetched again from the database:

Suppose Customer 10 moves from "Haarlem" to "Amsterdam":

```
int customerId = 10;

// fetch the customer with this Id, you can either use Find or FirstOrDefault:
Customer customerX = dbSet.Customers.Find(customerId);
Customer customerX = dbSet.Customers.Where(customer => customer.Id == customerId)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now change the customer:

```
customerX.City = "Amsterdam";
```

Fetch the Customer again:
Customer customerY = dbSet.Customers.Find(customerId);

This Customer was already in the ChangeTracker, you get the changed value from the ChangeTracker. customerY lives in "Amsterdam"

```
Customer customerZ = dbSet.Customers.Where(customer => customer.Id == customerId)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

customerZ is queried from the database. You haven't saved your changes, so this customer still lives in "Haarlem". If someone else has moved this Customer to "Rotterdam", you get the Customer from "Rotterdam".

So when asking for the same object again by primary key, it depends what you want, whether you want to use `Find` or `Where(... => ... Id == id).FirstOrDefault()`

By the way, I don't know whether this will override the originally fetched customer. You can check this, by checking whether `Object.ReferenceEquals(CustomerX, CustomerZ)` or check if CustomerX lives in "Haarlem" or "Amsterdam". My guess would be that this customer is overwritten by the newly fetched data.

So be careful which one you choose if you fetch the same item again.

### There's room for improvement.

Usually the dbContext has a very short life:

```
using (var dbContext = new CustomerDbContext())
{
     // Fetch an item, change it and SaveChanges
}
```

But sometimes you fetch a lot of items. If you fetch them all without using Select, all fetched items will be in the ChangeTracker:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var newYorkCustomers = dbContext.Customers
        .Where(customer => customer.City == "New York")
        .ToList();
    this.Display(newYorkCustomers);
```

This will have put thousands of Customers in the ChangeTracker. Now suppose you only change the first Customer and call SaveChanges:

```
    newYorkCustomer[0].Obsolete = true;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The code will have to check all 100,000 Customers in the ChangeTracker to see which one is changed.

> Whenever you query data, always use Select to fetch the data, and select only the properties that you plan to change. Only fetch without Select if you plan to update the fetched items.

This is also the case for `Include`. If you fetch "Customers with their Orders" only use Include if you plan to update the fetched Orders, if not, use Select

Answer (score 0):

```
int addressId = 234 //put your address id in here    

var address = dbContext.Addresses.Where(a => a.Id == addressId).SingleOrDefault();
    
                if (address == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException();
```

Note: you are fetching only one address because you said that Id is unique, so use SingleOrDefault instead.

Comment: Or just call `DbSet.Find`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - That is possible, but he is passing ID as parameter only, not the whole address object.

Comment: Which is what `Find` also does. `dbContext.Addresses.Find(addressId)` or `dbContext.Addresses.SingeOrDefault(a.Id=addressId)` would work the same way

Comment: A significant difference is that `Find` will check for any already loaded entities with the same ID